# Can I reset ion-content height on button click?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

Can I reset ion-content scroll height on button click? I need to switch footer on button click, but the content height remains same

Comment: I could hide the footer, but "scroll-content" margin-bottom not getting reset

Answer (score 1):

Just like you can see in the [Content docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/content/Content/#resize):

> **resize()**
>
> Tell the content to recalculate its dimensions. **This should
>   be called after dynamically adding/removing headers, footers, or tabs.**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export class MyPage{
  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;
  public showFooter: boolean = true;

  hideFooter() {
    this.showFooter = false;
    this.content.resize(); // Tell the content to recalculate its dimensions
  }

  showFooter() {
    this.showFooter = true;
    this.content.resize(); // Tell the content to recalculate its dimensions
  }
}
```